# If derivative of f(x) is f'(x), then what is the integral of (f'(x))^2 in terms of f(x)?

Tags: integral-transforms, functional-calculus

Is there some procedure for figuring this out or am I venturing into unsolved territory here?

Comment: I don't think that $\int f'(x)^2 dx$ can be stated in terms of $f(x)$.

Comment: It seems unlikely. Compare: $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, $f(x)=x$, and $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: If $f(x)=e^{x^2}$, then $(f'(x))^2$ doesn't have an antiderivative in closed form in terms of the familiar functions of intro Calculus.